# dont give any data from a connection in C

Tags: c, sockets, networking

For connecting to a web server I use below code in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 4455

void main()
{
    int clientSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    char buffer[1024];

    clientSocket=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) ;
    printf("[+]client socket created successfully.\n");

    memset(&serverAddr,'\0',sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port=htons(PORT);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("https://www.google.com/");

    connect(clientSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr,sizeof(serverAddr));
    printf("[+]connected to the server\n");

    recv(clientSocket,buffer,1024,0);
    printf("[+]data received is %s\n",buffer);

    printf("[+]closing the connection\n");
}
```

But when I compile and run the code, it doss not receive any data, or the received data is not valid.

For example, received data from Google is :

> ��5��

How can I fix it?

Comment: You cannot call `recv` and access the data buffer without checking its return value and `errno` error variable (that could hide _"I don't have data"_ or _"the connection is closed"_ errors). You should loop forever with recv printing data only when its retutn value is > 0.

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking the return values from your networking function calls, so you have no idea whether they succeeded or failed. It's possible that *all* your calls failed, and your code is just printing the random data in the uninitialized array `buffer`.

In addtion, you're doing a lookup for `https://google.com`, which is a URI, not an address. Most likely `inet_addr()` is not the right function to resolve a name to an IP address, even if you had an IP address, which you don't. You probably need to start with `gethostbyname()`.

Most importantly, even if you *do* manage to make a network connection to Google's HTTPS service, you'll be dealing with encrypted data, so you won't be able to process it unless you set up a encrypted TLS session. That's a long way from being straightforward, and most people use libraries like OpenSSL for this kind of thing.

I suspect that some of the problems I've noticed could have been spotted by your C compiler, if you turned its warning level up.

If you want to practice socket programming, I'd recommend that you start with a server that accepts simple, plaintext communication. If you want to practice socket programming with encryption, I'd recommend that you investigate OpenSSL or some similar library, or settle in for a *lot* of hard work. If you just want to make HTTP requests from your application, whether encrypted or not, I'd suggest looking at library like `libcurl`, which makes this kind of thing very easy.

There are loads and loads of C socket programming examples, on SO and many other places, if you need inspiration.